# Mapping in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I wanted to do mapping of two Data Frames on a common column.
Lets say,

My First Data Frame:

```
>>> df
   Task  Emp
0  1     aa
1  1     bb
2  2     cc
```

My second DataFrame:

```
>>> df1
   Task  Days
0  1      12
1  2      23
```

My Requirement is:

```
>>> Result
   Emp  Days
0  aa   12
1  bb   12
2  cc   23
```

Unable to do the mapping on the DataFrame in pandas. What is the best way to do so for huge no of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a merge:

```
pd.merge(df, df1, on='Task')
```

Output:

```
    Emp Days
0   aa  12
1   bb  12
2   cc  23
```

If your dataframes are big (and especially if you have duplicate values of 'Task' in both dataframes) you will run into memory problems though. This is not specific to the merge function but comes from the fact that it will join the values of 'Emp' and 'Days' on every common value of 'Task'.

Comment: It's the same exact answer as one already provided 20 minutes ago.

Comment: @piRSquared I started writing before the answer was posted. Plus it's not the exact same answer since I've explained the limitations of the approach...

Comment: @piRSquared By the way, your approach using concat will fail when you have duplicate values. For instance:

df:
`Task Emp`
`5 cc`
`4 cc`
`8 cc`
`3 aa`
`2 aa`
`6 aa`
`4 bb`
`6 cc`

df1:
`Task Day`
`1 5`
`7 3`
`0 6`
`6 7`
`8 1`
`9 7`
`5 9`
`9 3`
`3 8`

Answer (score 4):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df.rename(columns={'Task':'Days'}, inplace=True)
df['Days'] = df['Days'].map(df1.set_index('Task')['Days'])
df = df[['Emp','Days']]
print (df)
  Emp  Days
0  aa    12
1  bb    12
2  cc    23
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
pd.concat([d.set_index('Task') for d in [df, df1]], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

As pointed out by @Borja

> @piRSquared By the way, your approach using concat will fail when you
>   have duplicate values. For instance: df: Task Emp 5   cc 4    cc 8    cc 3    aa
>   2 aa 6    aa 4    bb 6    cc df1: Task    Day 1 5 7   3 0 6 6 7 8 1 9 7 5 9 9 3 3 8

This shouldn't be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the already given answers I have done a small performance test of the answers by [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336654/pirsquared), [Borja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5798668/borja), and [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael):

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

setup = """
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

# number of unique tasks
numTasks = %s
# number of rows in df
numRows = %s

## creating df
# columns for df
col1 = np.random.choice( range(numTasks), numRows )
col2 = np.random.choice( list(string.letters), numRows )

df = pd.DataFrame( { 'Task': col1,
                     'Emp':col2} )
df = df.sort_values( "Task" ).reset_index( drop=True )

# creating df1
tasks = df.Task.unique()
nTasks = len(tasks)

df1 = pd.DataFrame( { 'Task': tasks,
                      'Days': np.random.permutation( range(nTasks) ) } )

"""

solutionPiRSquared = """
pd.concat([d.set_index('Task') for d in [df, df1]], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
"""

solutionBorja = """
pd.merge(df, df1, on='Task')
"""

solutionJezrael = """
df.rename(columns={'Task':'Days'}, inplace=True)
df['Days'] = df['Days'].map(df1.set_index('Task')['Days'])
df = df[['Emp','Days']]
"""

numRepetitions = int( 100 )

solutions = [ { 'by': 'piRSquared',
                'code': solutionPiRSquared,
                'min': None,
                'max': None,
                'mean': None,
                'std': None },
              { 'by': 'borja',
                'code': solutionBorja,
                'min': None,
                'max': None,
                'mean': None,
                'std': None },
              { 'by': 'jezrael',
                'code':  solutionJezrael,
                'min': None,
                'max': None,
                'mean': None,
                'std': None  } ]

# test several settings for number of tasks and number of rows
# for each setup each solution is executed <numRepetition> times
# and execution time is measured. min, max, mean, and standard 
# deviation is calculated.
for (NUM_TASKS,NUM_ROWS) in [ (10,1000),
                              (100,10000),
                              (1000,10000),
                              (1000,100000),
                              (1000,1000000),
                              (10000,1000000),
                              (100000,1000000)]:
    print "-----------------------------------------"
    print "number of rows:",NUM_ROWS
    print "number of tasks:",NUM_TASKS
    print

    for solution in solutions:
        #print "solution by",solution['by']
        result = np.array( timeit.repeat( solution["code"], setup=setup % (NUM_TASKS,NUM_ROWS), number=1, repeat=numRepetitions ) )

        solution['min'] = result.min()
        solution['max'] = result.max()
        solution['mean'] = result.mean()
        solution['std'] = result.std()

    # sort solutions regarding the their mean value
    solutions.sort( key=lambda s: s['mean'] )

    best = solutions[0]['mean']

    # print sorted results along with relative increase of
    # execution time relative to the fastest solution (for current
    # setup
    for idx,solution in enumerate(solutions):
        d = { 'idx': idx+1,
              'rel': "[rel to best: +{:.2f}]".format(100*(solution['mean']-best)/best) if idx>0 else '[best]',
              'by': solution["by"],
              'min': solution["min"],
              'max': solution["max"],
              'mean': solution["mean"],
              'std': solution["std"] }

        print "{idx}. {rel}: solution by {by}".format( **d )
        print "    min: {min:.4f}, mean: {mean:.4f}, std: {std:.4f}, max: {max:.4f})".format( **d )

    print "-----------------------------------------"
```

several settings for `numTasks`, i.e., number of unique tasks in df and `numRows`, i.e., number of rows in df are tested and statistics of execution time is calculated. that gives me on my machine (Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU P8700 @ 2.53GHz × 2) with python2.7:

```
-----------------------------------------
number of rows: 1000
number of tasks: 10

1. [best]: solution by borja
    min: 0.0020, mean: 0.0021, std: 0.0001, max: 0.0026)
2. [rel to best: +3.12]: solution by piRSquared
    min: 0.0021, mean: 0.0022, std: 0.0002, max: 0.0030)
3. [rel to best: +14.46]: solution by jezrael
    min: 0.0023, mean: 0.0024, std: 0.0002, max: 0.0032)
-----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
number of rows: 10000
number of tasks: 100

1. [best]: solution by piRSquared
    min: 0.0026, mean: 0.0028, std: 0.0002, max: 0.0040)
2. [rel to best: +13.39]: solution by borja
    min: 0.0028, mean: 0.0031, std: 0.0009, max: 0.0119)
3. [rel to best: +23.38]: solution by jezrael
    min: 0.0033, mean: 0.0034, std: 0.0002, max: 0.0043)
-----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
number of rows: 10000
number of tasks: 1000

1. [best]: solution by piRSquared
    min: 0.0027, mean: 0.0030, std: 0.0003, max: 0.0044)
2. [rel to best: +5.63]: solution by borja
    min: 0.0030, mean: 0.0031, std: 0.0002, max: 0.0040)
3. [rel to best: +22.01]: solution by jezrael
    min: 0.0034, mean: 0.0036, std: 0.0002, max: 0.0046)
-----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
number of rows: 100000
number of tasks: 1000

1. [best]: solution by piRSquared
    min: 0.0092, mean: 0.0099, std: 0.0008, max: 0.0141)
2. [rel to best: +39.06]: solution by borja
    min: 0.0130, mean: 0.0137, std: 0.0009, max: 0.0170)
3. [rel to best: +71.95]: solution by jezrael
    min: 0.0163, mean: 0.0170, std: 0.0006, max: 0.0192)
-----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
number of rows: 1000000
number of tasks: 1000

1. [best]: solution by piRSquared
    min: 0.0882, mean: 0.0915, std: 0.0025, max: 0.1013)
2. [rel to best: +50.27]: solution by borja
    min: 0.1256, mean: 0.1375, std: 0.0104, max: 0.1828)
3. [rel to best: +75.97]: solution by jezrael
    min: 0.1557, mean: 0.1610, std: 0.0047, max: 0.1862)
-----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
number of rows: 1000000
number of tasks: 10000

1. [best]: solution by piRSquared
    min: 0.0887, mean: 0.0949, std: 0.0059, max: 0.1282)
2. [rel to best: +41.71]: solution by borja
    min: 0.1247, mean: 0.1345, std: 0.0055, max: 0.1621)
3. [rel to best: +84.01]: solution by jezrael
    min: 0.1668, mean: 0.1746, std: 0.0072, max: 0.2146)
-----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
number of rows: 1000000
number of tasks: 100000

1. [best]: solution by piRSquared
    min: 0.0959, mean: 0.1006, std: 0.0036, max: 0.1177)
2. [rel to best: +51.91]: solution by borja
    min: 0.1473, mean: 0.1528, std: 0.0047, max: 0.1800)
3. [rel to best: +77.68]: solution by jezrael
    min: 0.1730, mean: 0.1787, std: 0.0059, max: 0.2087)
-----------------------------------------
```

[concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) outperforms [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) here in this context.